# Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined - but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, velocity, apache-velocity

In an application based on templates rendered by Apache Velocity I am trying to include vue.js components. I am however experiencing the "Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined" when trying to use the parts of the application where vue.js is supposed to be present.

What puzzles me is that this error is not consistent. It does happen most of the time, however every now and then it will work flawlessly. From my research online both here on SO and elsewhere I've not found anyone who has had an inconsistency like this. For everyone else it appears to either work 100% of the time or 0% of the time.

For now I would like to understand the reason for why this happens and why it is so inconsistent.

**account-baskets-app.vm:**

```
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="/themes/javascript/vue.js"></script>

#parse_component("vue/account-basket-list-vue")
#parse_component("vue/account-basket-list-row-vue")

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#account-baskets-vue'
    })
</script>
```

**Console output:**

```
account-baskets:953 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at account-baskets:953
    (anonymous) @ account-baskets:953
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

**Network response:**

The response is the content of https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js

Answer (score 0):

It should be vue not loaded when you use it.
Had you check is there a network error when load vue.js use script?
If Vue had loaded there should be a golbal Vue func.
[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>


<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: I am loading it locally and not using an external CDN. I suspected network issues but there weren't any errors associated with loading the script. Other than that I am not sure what you are trying to say with your answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: Tt is weird if there is not a network error when load vue. 
Any way you can change <script src="/themes/javascript/vue.js"></script>
 to <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tried with that CDN now but the function still doesn't register even though the script is included.